# Which end of line character should I use?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one page with textarea which content is saved into database.
The content looks like this:

```
before
--------------
after
```

Now I need to split the text into "before" and "after" - without any new line signs.

So my questions are:
On what does the EOL character depends?
a) on a platform user is running
b) on a PHP server's platform
c) on a DB server's platform

Is there a better cross-platform solution?

```
$string_exploded = explode( "\n". $delimiter. "\n", $string );

if( count($string_exploded) === 1 )
{
    $string_exploded = explode( "\r\n". $delimiter. "\r\n", $string );
}
```

Thank you all for answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `PHP_EOL`. This will conform to the machine's proper line ending.

If you're just pulling from the database, you should be exploding with the same character you used to join them.

Even if you're worried about having whitespace at the end of your strings, just use `trim` afterwards to be happy with yourself.

Comment: PHP_EOL's perfect if you're not planning on moving the file between platforms. Otherwise, you will have to manually use the target platform's line-end char(s). But otherwise, spot on. +1.

Comment: trim is definitely the best solution

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, if you don't want to have to worry about what line endings might appear in your database is to use [preg_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead.

Something like this:

```
$string_exploded = preg_split('/(\\n|\\r\\n)' . $delimiter . '(\\n|\\r\\n)/', $string);
```

This has the added benefit that you can use the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` to have it automatically discard any empty entries if your data could contain double delimiters with no data between.